# tkinter progressbar indeterminate

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code starts the progress bar by clicking start

```
# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x120')
root.title('Progressbar Demo')

root.grid()

# progressbar
pb = ttk.Progressbar(
    root,
    orient='horizontal',
    mode='indeterminate',
    length=280
)
# place the progressbar
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)



start_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Start',
    command=pb.start
    )
start_button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E)


root.mainloop()
```

how can the progressbar be started without a button? so just by calling a function?
So basically I want the progressbar to start directly by executing the code.
Something like this:

```
# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x120')
root.title('Progressbar Demo')

root.grid()

# progressbar
pb = ttk.Progressbar(
    root,
    orient='horizontal',
    mode='indeterminate',
    length=280
)
# place the progressbar
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)


pb.start

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dont update this question with new question, instead ask a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I've made a slight change to your code, calling in specifics imports from the Tkinter libraries. which can be seen below. This avoids using "from Tkinter import *" which can cause issues later down the line.

```
from tkinter import Tk 
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar 

# root window 
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('300x120') 
root.title('Progressbar Demo')

root.grid()

# progressbar 
pb = Progressbar(
    root,
    orient='horizontal',
    mode='indeterminate',
    length=280 )

# place the progressbar 
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)
```

This is the code that calls the progress bar to start on execution. You needed to add parentheses after calling the "pb.start". The code should work how you want now.

```
pb.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, another question arose for me.
I added the following code to your example and by executing you see:
pb.start() starts after print-commands. Do you now what is the reason for that?

pb.start()
import time
print("Before the sleep statement")
time.sleep(5)
print("After the sleep statement")
root.mainloop()

Comment: I'll look into it for you, I'll hit you back when I've got something.

Comment: okay thanks. I have created a new question for it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085192/progressbar-starts-after-print-statements