# Progressbar starts after print statements

Tags: python, tkinter

Why is the progressbar starting after the print-commands?

I want to start the progressbar first. And wenn the 2nd print command ("After the sleep statement") was excecuted, I want to stop the progressbar. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import Tk 
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar 
import time

# root window 
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('300x120') 
root.title('Progressbar Demo')

root.grid()

# progressbar 
pb = Progressbar(
    root,
    orient='horizontal',
    mode='indeterminate',
    length=280 )

# place the progressbar 
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)

pb.start()



print("Before the sleep statement")
time.sleep(5)
print("After the sleep statement")

# pb.stop()

root.mainloop()
```

The current problem is that the progressbar is only started after time.sleep command.

Comment: Try removing the `time.sleep(5)`. Instead use `root.after(5000, pb.stop)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method)

Comment: Sleep was just as an example. In fact I want to place functions between pb.start() and pb.stop()

Comment: Do those functions use `tkinter`?

Comment: No. I just want to have a progress bar, when all functions have been carried out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The progress bar and all graphical elements of tkinter are launched from main loop (`root.mainloop()`). So, sleeping is done before the main loop. If you want so, you should implement spleeping IN main loop.

Furthermore, for a non-instantaneous processing, it's recommended to use a separate thread (e.g. with `threading.Tread`) to avoid blocking the GUI thread.

You can do something like this :

```
import threading
import time

from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar


# root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x120')
root.title('Progressbar Demo')

root.grid()

# progressbar
pb = Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate', length=280)
# place the progressbar
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)

def statement():
    pb.start()
    print("Before the sleep statement")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("After the sleep statement")
    pb.stop()

button = Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=statement).start())
button.grid(column=0, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it also possible without a button? So it starts 
automatically?

Comment: It isn't a good idea to use call `tkinter` methods from other threads. It can crash the python interpreter without giving you a traceback.

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm ok with you (here pb.start and pb.stop), but it's here a small demonstrator. Better code is to make a complet GUI.

Comment: I am saying that you shouldn't use any methods on any `tkinter` widgets from your `statement` function.

Comment: When I click a 2nd time on button, the following RuntimeError is showing: "threads can only be started once".
can that be bypassed somehow?

Comment: @AdlerMüller Fixed the code in this answer so that you aren't going to get that error, if you press the button twice.

Comment: Wow, this answer was fast and accurate. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

@Kaz's answer without the need for the button:

```py
import threading
import time

from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar


# root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x120')
root.title('Progressbar Demo')

# progressbar
pb = Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=280)
pb.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)

def statement():
    global stop_the_progressbar
    print("Before the sleep statement")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("After the sleep statement")
    stop_the_progressbar = True

def tkinter_loop():
    if stop_the_progressbar:
        pb.stop()
    else:
        root.after(100, tkinter_loop)

# Start the progressbar
pb.start()
threading.Thread(target=statement, daemon=True).start()
stop_the_progressbar = False
tkinter_loop()

root.mainloop()
```

It uses a `.after` loop to check if the progressbar should be stopped. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) for more details on how `.after` works. Also please note that you shouldn't call any `tkinter` methods from the new thread.

This example doesn't run well on IDLE because of a bug in IDLE. The text `"Before the sleep statement"` will be printed after the thread stops but it actually runs at the correct time.

Comment: Okay thanks for your solution.
When I click a 2nd time on button in  "Kaz" solution, the following RuntimeError is showing: "threads can only be started once".
can that be bypassed somehow?

Comment: @AdlerMüller I just edited that answer to solve that problem :D